# Is there a benefit to adding a prefix/suffix to a key in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When using an index as a key in React (in a case when no other value such as an id is present), are there any benefits of adding a prefix/suffix to the key?
An example below:

```
const Component = () => {
    const id = useId()

    return <>
        {array.map((item, index) => <div key={`${id}${index}`}>{item}</div>)}
    </>
}
```

Since using an index as a key is not recommended, I'm wondering if this approach has any benefits

Comment: No, there is no value

Comment: No, it doesn't really make a difference and you can probably rely on the auto-key behavior in this case, assuming you can't actually key off your `item`'s properties.

Comment: If you are not modifying your array, `index` as key would be fine

Comment: No, using index is not bad because it's just a number. Index is bad, because it changes when you filter or sort

Comment: You don't want the index tied to the component because the data should be tied to the component. If something in the page deletes a row, now some data will have different keys which could lead to issues when the react virtual dom tries to update the components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key` attribute is what allows React to keep track of which DOM element represents each of the items in the array you are looping through. This allows React to be more efficient with re-rendering, creation and destruction of elements should the array change.

The key should be representative of the data only, a unique key to identify that item in the array. Using the `index` in the `key` breaks this functionality, as the `key` will now vary depending on its position in the array. The key should be the same for the same item regardless of its position.

In your example, there is no performance benefit, as the keys for each element will change upon each render. The key should come from the `item` object, for example `key={item.id}` and should be a property that is immutable and unique to that object ideally.